# Receive [Upload missing dSYM required to process] when project's configured from multi - environments running a single target

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My Xcode workspace and Firebase project is configured to run multiple environments using a single target. The environments are PROD,DEV,BETA and QA. Although I am able to see analytic and performance data for all four environments in firebase, I'm receiving a "Upload missing dSYM required to process" error message for the  DEV, BETA and QA environments. Symbolicated Crash reports are appearing as expected for PROD but not the other three environments. I've also already set "Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file"
Attached is my current configuration.

[image]
I suspect that the issue is attributed to Firebase not parsing the correct *.plist as I'm also receiving this message in the console:
2019-01-15 16:51:37.522637-0500 [My App][7318:2157994] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025020] Analytics requires Google App ID from GoogleService-Info.plist. Your data may be lost. Google App ID has been changed. Original, new ID: [masked]:ios:[masked], [masked]:ios:[masked]

Any assistance or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Goto build setting of your project then search for "Debug information format" then set "Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file"

[image: debug information format]

Comment: Thanks, Yogesh, my workspace already already has this configuration set. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: If you are having issue with some build then you can access then from window -> Organizer  select the archive based on scheme and version, right click for show in finder, then show package contents and inside dSYMs folder you can find it. If archive not present then rebuild archive from version tag or commit.